# Java Script / window.open

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, window.open

I have this java script that I am using to open a new window, but I don't know how to pass user input into window with page extension.

This code will open page like this :https://xxx.mycompany.com/download/21373076

But I want to open this new window like this: with variable.html  <-- I need to add ".html" end of the window.open script.

```
javascript:(function(){var%20TKnum=prompt("Enter%20TK%20Number","");if%20(SRnum!=null)%20var%20w=window.open('https://xxx.mycompany.com/download/'+SRnum%20,'_blank');})();;  <-- How to add .html after '+SRnum%20'
```

Thank you

Comment: `SRnum+'.html'%20` ps.. this is an awful idea..

Comment: Remove space following `+SRnum`; e.g., `'..download/'+SRnum+'.html'`

Comment: @ guest271314 Thank you so much. This fix the problem and now it is working. I really appreciated your help. Thanksssss